# EditText value is 0?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm testing out my first app in C#. I have 4 fields in my axml file: 2 fields where you can input two numbers, 1 button and one field that is supposed to output the addition of the two numbers the user inputted when the button is clicked. and the app works but I always get 0 as output when I click on my button. So the problem could be, that I read the variables from the `EditText` wrong, maybe? Should use another field from the toolbox? I'm writing in Visual Studio! Here is my code:

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);


        EditText zahl1 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.zahl1);
        EditText zahl2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.zahl2);
        Button buttonErgebnis = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonErgebnis);
        TextView Ergebnis1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.emptyText);

        //convert string to int and save in variable 
        string a = zahl1.ToString();
        int Zahl1 = 99;
        int.TryParse(a, out Zahl1);

        string b = zahl2.ToString();
        int Zahl2 = 99;
        int.TryParse(a, out Zahl2);

        // add two numbers
        int ergebnis = Zahl1 + Zahl2;

        //output result if button is clicked 
        buttonErgebnis.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Ergebnis1.Text = ergebnis.ToString();
            };

    }
```

can u see the problem? I think it has something to do with my program not reading the first two numbers from the user right...

heads up: i got it to work with this code:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;


namespace OverWriteGPS

    [Activity(Label = "OverWriteGPS", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            EditText zahl1 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.zahl1);
            EditText zahl2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.zahl2);
            Button buttonErgebnis = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonErgebnis);
            TextView Ergebnis1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.emptyText);

            //output result if button is clicked 
            buttonErgebnis.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                //convert string to int and save in variable 
                string a = zahl1.Text;
                string b = zahl2.Text;
                int Zahl1, Zahl2, ergebnis;
                if ((int.TryParse(a, out Zahl1)) && (int.TryParse(b, out Zahl2)))
                {
                    ergebnis = Zahl1 + Zahl2;
                } else
                {
                    ergebnis = -1;
                }


                Ergebnis1.Text = ergebnis.ToString();
            };

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must perform the sum **after** the button is clicked.

Move the addition like here:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

    EditText zahl1 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.zahl1);
    EditText zahl2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.zahl2);
    Button buttonErgebnis = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonErgebnis);
    TextView Ergebnis1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.emptyText);

    //output result if button is clicked 
    buttonErgebnis.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            //convert string to int and save in variable 
            string a = zahl1.ToString();
            int Zahl1 = 99;
            int.TryParse(a, out Zahl1);

            string b = zahl2.ToString();
            int Zahl2 = 99;
            int.TryParse(a, out Zahl2);

            // add two numbers
            int ergebnis = Zahl1 + Zahl2;

            Ergebnis1.Text = ergebnis.ToString();
        };

}
```

However, you are not using the values you read form the user input. For some reason, you use 99. You may want to change that.

Comment: hey thanks! I tried that, yet it still gives me 0 as a result... so i just set the ints to 99 because of trying omething out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get `EditText` values within Click  like below:

```
//output result if button is clicked 
buttonErgebnis.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    //Need to get values of Zahl1  and Zahl2  here 
    string str1 = Zahl1  .Text; 
    string str2 = Zahl1  .Text; 
    // add two numbers
    int ergebnis = str1 + str2 ;
    Ergebnis1.Text = ergebnis.ToString();
};
```